# Derive $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How exactly would I go about this? I am thinking  by showing that for all subsets $B$ of a universal set $U$, $U \cup B = U$. But then what?

Comment: Use the set equality template: start with an element on the LHS and prove that it is in the RHS.  Then, start with the element on the RHS and prove that it in the LHS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A \cap B \subset A $ and $A \subset A \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow   \ \ \ \ A \cup (A \cap B) \subset A$

Conversely, $ \ \ \ \   A \subset A \cup (A \cap B)$

Therefore  $ \ \\ \  A = A \cup (A \cap B)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A \cap B$ is necessarily a subset of $A$. Anything that is in $A \cap B$ is, by definition, in $A$.

Then note that taking the union of a set and one of that set's subsets is necessarily that set: there's no element in the subset that isn't in the set. (In set-theoretic notation: if $B \subseteq A$ then $A \cup B = A$.)